# Best way to upgrade vim/gvim to 7.3 in Ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: vim, python, upgrade, gvim, ruby

I have to use Ubuntu 10.04 at work, and can't upgrade it. I'm using Vim/gVim 7.2.

I want to upgrade it to 7.3 (with Python and Ruby extension support). Which is the best way? Add an entry in `sources.lists` and install a 7.3 vim/gvim package from it, or build from source? What disadvantages would I have from each approach?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The first place to check is if there's a [backport](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports), but [there isn't](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=lucid-backports&searchon=names&keywords=vim), which isn't surprising since [maverick has vim 7.2 too](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=vim&searchon=names&suite=maverick).

The next thing to try is if someone's put up a repository with vim 7.3 packages somewhere, preferably a [PPA](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas). There are many [PPAs with vim](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas?name_filter=vim), including [several](https://launchpad.net/~passy/+archive/vim) [with](https://launchpad.net/~suraia/+archive/ppa)
[7.3](https://launchpad.net/~slaytanic/+archive/vim) (not an exhaustive list).

If you don't find a binary package anywhere or don't like the ones you find, the next easiest step is to grab the source package from [natty](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/vim), which has vim 7.3. Download the source package (`.dsc`, `.debian.tar.gz` and `.orig.tar.gz`), then run

```
apt-get install build-essential fakeroot
apt-get build-dep vim
dpkg-source -x vim_7.3.035+hg~8fdc12103333-1ubuntu2.dsc
cd vim-7.3.035+hg~8fdc12103333
# Edit debian/changelog to add an entry with your name and “recompiled for lucid”
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -us -uc -b -nc
```

If all goes well, you'll have binary packages for your distributions. If you run into missing dependencies or compilation errors, this has to be solved on a case-by-case basis.

The next thing to try is to compile the upstream 7.3 source with the packaging from your Ubuntu version. This gives you a nice and clean package, but it's a little more involved, so if you don't feel confident in doing this without instructions I recommend you just compile the upstream source.

If you end up compiling the upstream source, by default, you'll end up with the files under `/usr/local`, and it won't be easy to uninstall them, or even to know what you have. Whenever you install something without using the package manager, I recommend installing into a separate directory structure and creating symbolic links in `/usr/local` (or `~/usr` or whatever). [Stow](http://www.gnu.org/software/stow/) is nice for that:

- Install under `/usr/local/stow` (or `~/usr/stow` or wherever). With many programs, you can use something like `./configure --prefix=/usr/local/stow/vim-7.3`. This will put the main binary at `/usr/local/stow/vim-7.3/bin`, and so on.
- Run `stow vim-7.3` from the `/usr/local/stow` directory. This creates symbolic links in the “normal” directories, e.g. `/usr/local/bin/vim -> ../../stow/vim-7.3/bin/vim`.
- If you ever want to uninstall this program, just run `stow -D vim-7.3` to remove the symbolic links, and delete `/usr/local/stow/vim-7.3`.

There is also [xstow](http://xstow.sourceforge.net/) which is a similar, but more powerful programs (one of its benefits is that it can deal with conflicts).

Comment: I've never done something like creating specific binary package for my distribution. If I compile the upstream source into /usr/local, can I just exclude it after if something goes wrong? I've never done something like this before, because I'm afraid of breaking other packages (I've done this mess before with ubuntu 8.04 here, all my python installations were just f***ed up)

Comment: @Somebody: The advantage of installing a package (created by you or someone else) is that you can uninstall it easily. If you do compile the package, I recommend using (x)stow.

Comment: +1.  How have I never seen stow before? It looks fantastically useful.

Comment: Thanks, this worked like a charm in Ubuntu 10.10 with the 2:7.3.035+hg~8fdc12103333-1ubuntu7 sources from your natty link! I just had to `apt-get install python3-dev`.
Btw. for all who are wondering, you can install the debs using `sudo dpkg -i *.deb` and maybe remove the vim7.2 packages before.

Comment: The only problem I see is that you need to set the vim runtimepath to not be the `/usr/local/stow/vim-7.3/share/vim` directory but rather something like `/usr/local/share/vim` directory. I *think* you can do that with `--with-global-runtimepath=/usr/local/share/vim` but I could be wrong.

Comment: @TheDoctorWhat Good point, but setting the `runtimepath` is only necessary if you have third-party files to put there, which most people don't. Admittedly, people who compile the latest version are more likely to have these than average.

Comment: Another alternative is to use `./configure --prefix=/usr/local && make && make install prefix=/usr/local/stow/vim-7.3`

Answer (score 3):

Build from source. It will be quicker. Trying to both find and enable a repository for a one-off install like that will just cause you headaches further down the line.

Comment: No, getting a repository (when there is one) is quicker. Building a package is not necessarily quicker, but for programs with many compilation options (vim is one) getting the build steps of the distribution is recommended, because it is far more likely to give you a configuration you're comfortable with. Building a package is also a major win if you want to install on multiple machines.